# Good Programming Software

Tags: php, c, compiler-construction

What would you recommend as a GUI software to code in php, c, c++ software. Doesnt matter free or paid. I am looking for a solution that can support everything (compiling, debugging etc)

For windows

Thanks

Comment: It would help to know what OS you will be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is a very complete IDE and probably can satisfy all your needs. [NetBeans](http://www.eclipse.org/) is worth looking, too.

I, personally, just roll my own with [vim](http://www.vim.org/) and some scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those religious questions capable of endless arguument.  Some of the most popular are

- EMACS
- Vi/Vim
- TextMate
- Eclipse

I've also seen people speak well of SubEthaEdit, BBEdit, Smultron, and TextWrangler (that's weighted toward Mac apps since that's what I use normally.)

Comment: +1 for you and a close vote for the question. As you say, it's a religious argument. Personally, I'm a TextMate. :)

Answer (score 1):

For a light-weight but still feature rich solution, I think [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) strikes a fantastic balance.  I do all my programming (across several languages) in it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people like to have all their programming utilities in one. This is called an "Integrated Development Environment" or IDE. NetBeans and Eclipse are both IDEs (and Emacs can be an IDE if you use its advanced features.) The "standard" IDE for Windows development is Microsoft Visual Studio, although I personally can't stand using it.

But there's something to be said for keeping the functionality separate, and I'd suggest trying it that way. You end up with a cleaner and more "purpose-built" user interface for each separate task. Good programming editors for Windows include Notepad++ and Geany, neither of which is a full-on IDE.

Answer (score 1):

By GUI you mean: IDE? (ie 'Integrated Development Environment')
And I suggest [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) as a pretty good free solution for php.